# Is talking to myself mean that i am talking with Satan?

Tags: shaitan

Sometimes I talk to myself. Then there are two voices in my head. I ask a question an the other voice answers. Sometimes I am suprised at the answers it gives. I wouldn't be suprised if it was me right  ? What does this mean  ?

Answer (score 1):

It was commonly observed that people talk to them-self in order to resolve or to find some solution for their problems. But if anyone found some negative thoughts then he or she should avoid that thinking or talking. They should try to talk real persons, because if he or she continue this practice in large it will lead him/her separation from social community.

As per Islamic perspective there are many saying which talk about evil whispers. One of the hadith is mentioned below which talk about Waswaas (Whispers from the Shaytaan). These waswaas at any time or during prayer time comes from the Shaytaan.

"Allah's Messenger, the Satan intervenes between me and my prayer and my reciting of the Qur'an and he confounds me. Thereupon Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:, That is (the doing of a) Satan (devil) who is known as Khinzab, and when you perceive its effect, seek refuge with Allah from it and spit three times to your left. I did that and Allah dispelled that from me." [Sahih Muslim 2203]

If anyone feels that he/she is affected by this waswaas, then he/she should say: "Aamantu Billaahi wa Rasoolihi (I believe in Allah and His Messenger)".

Also try to stop thinking too much and try to distract or get yourself busy in some other usefull stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Brother here i am sharinbg a tip.Check the voice you hear in your head if it contains shirk or kufar in the light of  Quran and Sunnah.After checking if the thing is wrong then negate it and if the thing is right then  take it.Thats it.
we humans always talk with self and its very normal.The thing is that we have to check our thoughts.To check our thoughts earning of right knowlwdge is inevitable.